# Highcharts pies: errors on devices

Tags: highcharts

I am getting constant "undefined is not an object" errors on pie charts on iOS, using Highcharts 3.

To demonstrate: if I load the demo page www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic in iOS simulator, with the Debug Console activated, and simply press the mouse button and run the cursor across the pie, I get a continuous stream of these errors.

On an actual iPad, running a finger across the pie generates the same error-stream.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a grown-up to run this through in a context that actually tells us something about the problem. He got:

Error message: 
highcharts.js:148 
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'd.xAxis.zoomEnabled')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting, we logged and fixed the issue at https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1861.

The fix will be available with the next maintenance release in two or three weeks.